# GeoDjango make ValueError when migrate DataBase

Tags: django, django-models, migrate, django-migrations, geodjango

I want use GeoDjango and make model and do `makemigrations` & `migrate`
So GeometryField is made well in my table but show error message `ValueError: String input unrecognized as WKT EWKT, and HEXEWKB.`
What is this message and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

don't use field name like `polygon`, `geometry`, `geojson`, `linestring`
see the doc https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/geos/geometry.py#L709